# API usage Limit in Flurry?

Tags: flurry

Flurry says that The rate limit for the API is 1 request per second. In other words, you may call the API once every second. I could not understand this.it means whenever the event occurs in mobile Application  the request sends to server not as whole thing.Am I right? any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a queue in your application with the events you want to register with the API, and continuously try to send all items in that queue, with a one second interval.

Comment: please explain in detail again, is it possible  to send  without one second interval?  suppose if user presses continously  one button , will it be taken?

Comment: I don't know, Flurry isn't mine. Perhaps they'll block you if you send too much requests within a second of each other. Read their terms of service.

Answer (score 3):

When registering events you don't need to worry about API Limits. All events you fire are stored locally and when your session finishes the whole event package is sent to flurry server.